# MongoDB - find result where value is null or less than X

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB with two dates that define whether or not something is current. So I have an "end_date" that can be null, or may have a time value. An item that current has a null end_date or a time in the future. My query looks like this:

```
program_enrollments.find( {"start_date":{"$lte":1376982000},"end_date":[null,{"$gte ":1376982000}],"client":"52002d02cc94a31a0f000000"}, [] )
```

This looks proper to me, but do I need a different approach? I don't want to have a boolean flag that says whether or not the dates are current if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 40):

The $or operator could be quite cumbersome at times, especially if you have other fields with multiple options, then you'd have to put all the $or's nested within an $and.

Another option could be to use the negation operator:

`"end_date": {"$not": {"$lt":1376982000}}`

This will give you the same results as

`$or: [{end_date: null}, {end_date: {$gte: 1376982000}}]`

And your query would look like this, which is somewhat cleaner IMO:

```
program_enrollments.find({
  start_date: {$lte: 1376982000},
  end_date: {$not: {$lt: 1376982000}},
  client:"52002d02cc94a31a0f000000"
})
```

Comment: Are there any unintended consequences of doing this? If not, this seems clearly better.

Comment: @DavidKong you can have problems if you mix types. I think that if types didn't match it result in false, so you would get `true` if you negate it and you would get `false` if used directly. However, I'm not sure and haven't checked it.

Answer (score 30):

You are looking for the `$or` operation, which accepts an array of operations.  It would be like so:

```
$or: [{end_date: null}, {end_date: {$gte: 1376982000}}]
```

Your entire query would look like:

```
program_enrollments.find({
  start_date: {$lte: 1376982000},
  $or: [
    {end_date: null}, 
    {end_date: {$gte: 1376982000}}
  ],
  client:"52002d02cc94a31a0f000000"
})
```

To scale, you will want to find a way to remove either the `$gte` and `$lte` operators.  MongoDB cannot use the combination of the `$lte` and `$gte` on different attributes in the query.

Answer (score 0):

The $and operator could be quite.especially if you have other fields with multiple options, then you'd have to put all the $or's nested within an $and.

db.program_enrollments.find({"$and":[{"$or":[{"object.key":{},{"object.key":{"$gt":"2021-01-01","$lt":"2021-01-31"}}}]},{"object.key":""}]})

Answer (score -2):

Instead of `{end_date: null}` you can ask if the variable exists using `{end_data: {$exists: false}}`. Note that if `end_date` is in the document with `null` value, then first one will work and second one doesn't.

Comment: `{end_date: null}` also covered the corner-case where the field was simply not present due to omission, `{end_data: {$exists: false}}` doesn't ... at least not when I tested with v3.0